# mongodb api for fetch in data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have below JSON:

```
{
  "program_objective": "",
  "program_type": "Post Graduate",
  "creation_date": "2020-01-04T04:45:28.418Z",
  "dstatus": "",
  "_id": "5e101e26a96cc905745721b0",
  "program_name": "Hardware",
  "short_code": "Hdw",
  "program_induc_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000Z",
  "program_cat": "Certificate",
  "program_years": "0",
  "program_months": "6",
  "depart_id1": "Msc IT ",
  "PEO": [
    {
      "_id": "5e1300d826c155310c6ae384",
      "peo": "Hardware",
      "weight": 212
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e1300d826c155310c6ae383",
      "peo": "Hardware",
      "weight": 212
    }
  ],
  "Name": [],
  "PO": [],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want the PEO value from above JSON but when I am trying to get "PEO":{}, it is returning null.

```
router.route('/getprogram/:id/PEO/').get((req, res, next) => {
    addmissionForm.programSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
        console.log(data.PEO)
        if (error) {
            return next(error)
        } else {
            res.json(data)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: So the result of `console.log(data.PEO)` is that you posted in the answer?

Comment: can you show the result of `console.log(data)`?